# TikZ node "below of" includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics

When I try to place a TikZ `node` `below of` another node that contains an `\includegraphics`-picture, it is not placed below the node, just below its center. I have the feeling the actual image dimensions (and in turn the node dimensions) are not known to the `below of` makro (with the words from an outsider).

I know many workarounds, but isn't there a "right" way to fix this?

**Example:**

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw = red] (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \node[draw = green, below of = image] {this is NOT below of `image`};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: mwe-result]

Comment: Use `below=of image` provided by `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` (or `below=3mm of image` to specify the distance), which is recommended by TikZ over the depracated `below of` key.

Comment: Thanks for all this insights! I guess, I didn't have the right concept of `below of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer the `below` key and use `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node[draw = red] (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \node[draw = green, below = 0mm of image] {this is NOT below of `image`};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can use node positioning like `image.south`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw = red] (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
    \node at (image.south)[draw = green, anchor=north] {this IS below of `image`!};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note you have to specify also the `anchor`.

This code produces

[image]

### Variation

You can play with nodes' label:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw = red,label={[draw=green,text=red]-90:this IS below of `image`!}] (image) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```